# Tools for converting JSON-LD ontologies to HTML documentation

Tags: ontology, documentation-generation, json-ld

I have a JSON-LD ontology that I'd like to convert to HTML-documentation.

I've found a few tools that can do that, Ontodocs (Python, generates nice documentation in different themes) and Widoco (Java). These seem to do the job pretty well, but there are some issues with them and I'm now trying to find other similar tools that can do this.

Many of the tools I have found are not really suited for JSON-LD, but more for RDF and OWL ontologies.

It seems that the Hydra specification is using ReSpec for this purpose, but I'm not too familiar with it, and I'd prefer Python for the generation of the documentation.

So, does anyone know of any alternatives to Ontodocs and Widoco?

Comment: This is a great question about bioinformatics, but totally off-topic for stackoverflow since it has nothing to do with programming nor with a tool commonly used by informaticians. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: JSON-LD is one of the RDF serialization formats. Just convert your file into another serialization format and feel free to use any tool for RDF documenting. But I'm not sure it is possible to ducument pure RDF (that do not use RDFS or OWL vocabularies).

Comment: I have done that as well, first convert JSON-LD to RDF, but that's not the approach I'd like to go about. I haven't really found any tools that would "just work" with JSON-LD.